# Excel VBA: Count occurrences below current cell till end of table

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am looking to count the number of occurrences of each item in a column using VBA. But I would like to make a counter which decreases i.e. to count the occurrences in the remaining cells

I have the following for example in the column

```
Column1
ABCD
ABCD
ABCD
XXXX
XXXX
YYYY
YYYY
YYYY
```

I am looking to add one more column to this table giving the count. So ideally after my formula, it should look like this

```
Column1 Computed
ABCD    2
ABCD    1
ABCD    0
XXXX    1
XXXX    0
YYYY    2
YYYY    1
YYYY    0
```

I have tried using formulas in R1C1 format in VBA

```
"=COUNTIF(R[0]C[-1]:R[35000]C[-1],[@Column1])"
```

35000 being an arbitrary value as I do not know how to find the count of entries until the end of the table. I would like to find the occurrence of current cell value in the remaining cells of the table column so that the count is filled up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick. 
LastRow gives the Last Row (your 35000) and the Count if written this way should give the remaining occurrences

```
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = mainWS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("B3").FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R[1]C[-1]:R" & LastRow & "C1,RC[-1])"
```

Because it is easier to understand the formula in Excel, I also write it below:

```
=COUNTIF(A2:$A$35000;A1)
```

Comment: Please upvote and mark one of us as the correct answer thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in column A and starts from Row2 and you want to place the formula in column B, then give this a try....

```
Dim lr As Long
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'Assuming data starts from Row2 in Column A and you want to place the formula in column B
Range("B2:B" & lr).formula = "=COUNTIF(A3:$A$" & lr + 1 & ",A2)"
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, i checked out the above answer and this one, both work fine, i am using this in my code at the moment.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it worked as desired. Please take a minute to accept the answer to mark your question as Solved. :)